# ld does not find math library -lm

Tags: gcc, libraries, ld

`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6` is present, `-lm` is present on the command line, but ld gives undefined references for all math symbols.

Similar situation with ncurses.

Thanks in advance.

Clarification, as requested below:

```
# apt-cache policy libc6-dev libc6-dev:i386
libc6-dev:
  Installed: 2.28-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.28-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.28-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6-dev:i386:
  Installed: 2.28-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.28-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.28-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libc6-dev libc6-dev:i386` to the question.

Comment: *Where* is `-lm` present on the command line? The order of linked libraries matters: see for example [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: The order of things on the command line was indeed the culprit. The author of the makefile tells me that modern C compilers do not impose this order anymore (while admitting that my compiler is not old ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The order of the options on the command line was wrong.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc as suggested above.